# Reverse Proxying With IIS 10

Tags: windows, iis, server, proxy, hosting

I am wondering how to go about reverse proxying a web application that's running on certain port through my locally hosted website.

OS: Windows Server 2019
Server: IIS 10

I have a domain with a forum. I am also hosting a game server. I want to create a subdomain so traffic will be routed to my web front on port 1624. There is no physical path to the game server as it's an extension of a master server hosted elsewhere.

I am looking for more information on how to do this. Do I need APR? Trees? Reverse proxy? Any info will help.

I already have my site configured and running on port 80 through cloud flare. I have records made for my subdomain. Server is up and running and I am able to access it. The only thing left to do is bind the ip and port to the sub domain.

Comment: It's called ARR, not APR, and you need to first finish the tutorial/example in order to fully understand what is a reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Can you make it more clear? Like what is the old URL  and  what is the new URL you want to it to be.